# Losing the Facebook state session key in Google Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: php, session, google-chrome, facebook-php-sdk

When requiring the login url from the facebook sdk a `state` is saved in the session to prevent CSRF, this is done in the `Facebook` class `setPersistentData($key, $value)` method:

```
$session_var_name = $this->constructSessionVariableName($key);
$_SESSION[$session_var_name] = $value;
```

After that, I made a `var_dump` of `$_SESSION` and `exit;` to be sure it's in there and nothing can alter the `$_SESSION` array. And voila, it's there:

```
...
'fb_451994004840680_state' => string '6de843508d52d3d4926275ab49280cef' (length=32)
...
```

So I change the `index.php` file to

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
exit;
```

and refresh. All previously set session elements are there, **but not the facebook state**.

So I tried the following: I added another (dummy state) key in the `setPersistentData($key, $value)` method:

```
$_SESSION[$session_var_name] = $value;
$_SESSION['fb_1234567890_state'] = '848a87592acd';
var_dump($_SESSION);
exit;
```

and both are set directly after var_dump:

```
'fb_451994004840680_state' => string '6de843508d52d3d4926275ab49280cef' (length=32)
'fb_1234567890_state' => string '848a87592acd' (length=12)
```

After refresh and var dumping in the index.php, only the dummy key exists:

```
'fb_1234567890_state' => string '848a87592acd' (length=12)
```

---

**How is this possible???**